# Forces on accelerating massless pulley

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics, free-body-diagram

Consider a massless pulley with string passed over it and connected to two masses. The string holding the pulley is pulled vertically upward with force F. My question is what would be the tension in each string connecting masses. I have calculated and it is not F/2 (if I am right). Here pulley is non inertial frame of reference. So I want to know how F=ma applies to the pulley where m=0 and net force ≠0.[image]

Comment: Unclear. Is the system of masses being accelerated upward or is the pulley pulled with constant velocity after the initial acceleration? If it is accelerated, is the acceleration constant? Are the masses equal to each other?

Comment: Pulley is pulled with force F. (see image added). The acceleration is constant and masses unequal

Comment: F=ma can't apply to the pulley. The pulley acts only as a directional transfer agent for the hanging masses and a connection point for the lifting force. The lifting force acts on the whole system, opposite the total weight accelerates the center of mass upward. If the masses are unequal, the differential weights will further accelerate the CoM relative to the pulley.

Comment: Why F=ma can't apply to the pulley?

Comment: Because you are choosing the mass of the pulley to be zero.  If don't want to do that, then you must conclude that the tensions on each side of the pulley are not equal to each other because there will be a torque and consequent angular acceleration as well as linear acceleration. The idea of a massless pulley is effectively taking the limit that $m_p/(m_1+m_2)$ approaches zero.

Comment: You can also analyze it using pseudo force on the whole accelerated system.

Comment: The answer by @dale conveys rather something else,I am confused

Comment: Could you confirm if the answer is $\frac {2Fm_1m_2}{(m_1+m_2)^2}$?

Answer (score 2):

Your calculation must contain a mistake somewhere. For any massless object the forces and the torques must sum to zero. This follows from Newton’s 2nd law: $F_{net}=ma$ so if $m=0$ then $F_{net}=0$ regardless of $a$.

In this case the two tensions must sum to F so that the net force on the pulley is zero and they must be equal so that the net torque on the pulley is zero. Therefore, they are each F/2.

Note that since the system as a whole is massive F may be non-zero and the center of mass of the system as a whole may accelerate. It is only the massless pulley which must have a balanced force and torque regardless of the acceleration.

Comment: I don’t understand the downvotes. Please leave a comment explaining so I can improve it.

Comment: The pulley is massless, but not the whole system - we can apply a force to the system as a whole and have a determinate acceleration, even if the system has massless components.

Comment: Sure. I never said otherwise. The forces on the massless pulleys must balance, but not the forces on the system as a whole which is massive. I will clarify the answer

Answer (score 2):

Treat the whole system first.  $F$ is pulling on the whole system by the equation:

$F-(m1+m2)g=(m1+m2)a$

where $a$ is the acceleration of the center of mass of the system.  In terms of the individual mass accelerations $a1$ and $a2$, the center of mass acceleration is

$a=\frac{m1\ a1+m2\ a2}{m1+m2}$

You should be able to finish the rest to get $a1$, $a2$, and $T$.  The acceleration of the pulley is the average of $a1$ and $a2$.

Applying the rest of the equations and solving, I also get the tension to be $F/2$, so I do not really understand the downvotes for the other answer by Dale.